# Bootstrapvalidation will not hide error message when the field is valid

Tags: jquery, bootstrapvalidator

I am using the bootstrapvalidator plugin, i know this is an old version that is no longer supported and the new version is called FormValidation (http://formvalidation.io/) but that now requires payment so i am looking for a quick fix to my issue.

The error is that even after the validation is a success, hovering over the green tick will still show the error message. So for example, when both the passwords are the same the message 'The new password and its confirm are not the same' is displayed.

The jQuery code is below:

```
$('#newPasswordForm')
    .bootstrapValidator({
        container: 'tooltip',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {

            password: {
                validators: {
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-.~]).{8,}$/,
                        message: 'Password must use a combination of at least 8 upper and lower case letters, numbers and symbols.'
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'You must enter your new password'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 8,
                        message: 'Password must be at least 8 characters in length'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'password_confirmation',
                        message: 'The new password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            },

            password_confirmation: {
                validMessage: '',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'You must confirm your new password'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'password',
                        message: 'The new password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    })
```

The form HTML is as follows:

```
   <form id="newPasswordForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$email}}" required autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">New Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="New Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password_confirmation" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="resetBtn">Set password</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: can you post html form here?

Comment: @BhumiShah i've added the form HTML above

Answer (score 1):

I have created demo and it is not showing error message on hover of green tick:

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/bKWgPz

Bootstrapvalidator version i have used is:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It turns out this is an issue with version 0.5.2. If you change the bootstrap validator to this version it should have the same issue. As this is only a minor change though i might be able to update to 0.5.3 on my site though without breaking anything. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I don't think it will break anything after upgrade.

Comment: After having done some testing, it appears using v0.5.3 breaks validation elsewhere on the site. Specifically relating to select inputs. Unless there is a fix i can do to this it may be a case of just  using another jquery validation library